# need help troubleshooting a function that searches for specific url links in an array of text

Tags: php

hey guys Im building a script by which Im attempting to find specific links in twitter text results

This script basically checks whether the text contains a url, then determines if that url is one of 6 specific urls, and if it matches outputs the original text into a new array Ive labeled as $imgtweets

the problem however is that despite the fact that I have about 4 text string in the array only one of them is matching and being returned in the $imgtweets array, Im having a hard time determining where Ive made the mistake, any help would go a long way!

this is my code, Ive had to make the array slightly smaller however because im not allowed to post more that 2 hyperlinks at this point:

```
<?php

$tweets = array(
         "Photo: therulesofagentleman: http://tumblr.com/xc52sgx6u7",
         "http://mypict.me/iysEX So this is Karly. Karly say hello to the world. We've been at this a while when your fans (cont)",
         "this is some test text that doesnt contain any links for testing purposes");

         $imgtweets = array();

         foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
         preg_match_all("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t<]*)#ise", $tweet, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

         $tweetlinks = $matches[0];
         if (!empty($tweetlinks)){

         foreach($tweetlinks as $key => $link) {

         if (substr($link,0,14)=="http://lockerz" || substr($link,0,12)=="http://yfrog"
         || substr($link,0,14)=="http://twitpic" || substr($link,0,13)=="http://tumblr"
         || substr($link,0,13)=="http://mypict" || substr($link,0,14)=="http://instagr"  )
         {
          array_push($imgtweets,"$tweet");
          }
       }
      }
     }
       print_r($imgtweets);

?>
```

Comment: too bad formatted and too hard to understand. retry.

Comment: sorry for the first section of the code Im not able to get it to format properly on the site

Comment: there it is, took a second lol

Comment: you can still edit it because it's still pretty bad formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you can replace all your code with something like

```
$hosts  = "lockerz|yfrog|twitpic|etc";
$regexp = "~http://($hosts)~";

$img_tweets = preg_grep($regexp, $all_tweets);
```

Comment: interesting, im still a little new to php, very sorry, however how would i parse through a for each loop of tweets with this new function?

Comment: Im just looking up this function right now, seems very useful! Im going to attempt to implement It right now and see what it gives me, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: wow, you sir are a genius! thanks for pointing me down the right path, very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using substr you could use an array and str_replace

```
 $urls = array(*****your urls*****);
 foreach($tweets as $tweet) 
 {
   str_replace($urls, '', $tweet, $count);
   if ($count)
   {
      array_push($imgtweets,"$tweet");
   }
 }
```